# how to do masking/hiding email address in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

i have an issue, i have to apply masking/hiding part of email address in c#. example

```
jhon@abc.com==> jh**n@abc.com
bigjhon@abc.com==> bi****n@abc.com
brotherhood@abc.com==>br*******od@abc.com
```

i have this code but its giving exception for some emails. "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
for (int i = 0; i < eml.Length; i++)
{
 int j = i == (eml.Length - 1) ? 0 : 1;
 cc = eml[i].ToString();
 if (i <= 1)
 {
  dispeml += cc;
 }
 else 
 if (eml[i + (j + k)].ToString() == "@")
 {
  dispeml += cc;
  k = 0;
  fl = 1;
 }
 else 
 if (eml[i + j].ToString() == "@")
 {
  dispeml += cc;
  fl = 1;
 }
 else 
 if (fl == 1)
 {
  dispeml += cc;
 }
 else
 {
  dispeml += "*";
 }
}
```

Comment: "giving exception for some emails": I suppose we could guess what they are. But it would be better to include the details of which emails are failing with which exception and what point in the code.

Comment: actually that code is live on website and i don't got those email address details but i got only this error.

Comment: Why don't you start your debugger and look what happen in this code? You are in the best position to discover the fault. Just put a breakpoint at the start of this code and run the debugger.

Comment: i did but its fine, that's why i put it here. may be i'm missing some thing so other can help me

Comment: Have you example test email addresses you can show which fail?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is a approach to solve this with Regex

```
string input = "jhon@abc.com";
string pattern = @"(?<=[\w]{1})[\w\-._\+%]*(?=[\w]{1}@)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => new string('*', m.Length));
//j**n@abc.com
```

https://regex101.com/r/hQjp2O/1

**Explanation**:

`(?<=[\w]{1})` the name has to start with 1 word-character

`[\w\-._\+%]*` the replacement-part can contain 0-n word characters including `-_.+%`

`(?=[\w]{1}@)` the name has to end with one word character followed by a `@`

Depending on the amount of characters you want to remain unchanged you can change `{1}` to `{2}` or something else at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: How would I make this affect the domain of the e-mail address as well?

Comment: @Djorge that's a bit tricky because the domain technically cold be `@foo`, `@foo.bar.com` or `@192.168.1.1` beside the trivial case `@foo.com`

Comment: I ended up adding `|(?<=@[\w]{1})[\w-_\+%]*(?=\.)` to the end of your regex to get what I wanted, doesn't handle `@foo` though.

Comment: @Djorge If you remove the at sign in your addition, you can also match multiple domain parts. The whole expression would be (?<=[\w]{1})[\w-\._\+%]*(?=[\w]{1}@)|(?<=[\w]{1})[\w-_\+%]*(?=\.) then

Comment: Here is a fun anomaly I came across. Try jhon+1@abc.com (does not mask anything) - then try jhon+12@abc.com (masks as expected)

Answer (score 16):

If you always want to mask anything between first character and last character before @ with fixed number of masked characters , you can use the below

```
var email="abcdef@ghij.com";
var maskedEmail = string.Format("{0}****{1}", email[0], 
email.Substring(email.IndexOf('@')-1));
```

You can alter the above line for your requirement.

The above line will give you the result "a****f@ghij.com"

Note that masking the email always with a fixed number of characters will make it difficult to guess the email and is slightly more secure.

ex: ab@c.com

after mask: a****b@c.com

Answer (score 4):

I can't see where your k variable is initialised in your code snippet. If I had to take a wild stab as to why you are getting an index out of bounds exception that would be my stab.

Although I would say that you could achieve something very similar to what you are doing using Regex. I did it like this:

```
public string ObfuscateEmail(string email)
{
    var displayCase = email;

    var partToBeObfuscated = Regex.Match(displayCase, @"[^@]*").Value;
    if (partToBeObfuscated.Length - 3 > 0) {
        var obfuscation = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < partToBeObfuscated.Length - 3; i++) obfuscation += "*";
        displayCase = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",  displayCase[0], displayCase[1], obfuscation, displayCase.Substring(partToBeObfuscated.Length - 1));
    } else if (partToBeObfuscated.Length - 3 == 0) {
        displayCase = String.Format("{0}*{1}", displayCase[0], displayCase.Substring(2));
    }

    return displayCase;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of all your test cases provided passing pretty close to what you were describing https://dotnetfiddle.net/fU2RUo

[EDIT] My code doesn't try to obfuscate emails whose addresses before the @ are less than 3 characters long, if this is a requirement you would need to amend the code but I didn't think it was a very realistic case to have to build a case for.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this method as it was easier to customize for my specific masking requirements.

- Input:   myemail@address.com
- Output:  m****il@*******.com

I hope this helps someone. If so, please mark the answer helpful.

```
public static string MaskEmail(this string email)
    {            
        var emailsplit = email.Split('@');
        var newsplit = emailsplit[1].Split('.');
        char[] array1 = emailsplit[0].ToCharArray();
        char[] array2 = newsplit[0].ToCharArray();
        var output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array1.Length > 4)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == array1.Length - 1 || i == array1.Length - 2)
                {
                    output += array1[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    output += "*";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    output += array1[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    output += "*";
                }
            }              
        }
        output += "@";
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++) output += "*";
        for (int i = 1; i < newsplit.Length; i++) output += "." + newsplit[i];

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to mask emails like this A****B@C****D.com. This also works with emails that have multiple dots or no domain extension.

```
public string MaskEmail(string email)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || !email.Contains("@"))
        return email;

    string[] emailArr = email.Split('@');
    string domainExt = Path.GetExtension(email);

    string maskedEmail = string.Format("{0}****{1}@{2}****{3}{4}",
        emailArr[0][0],
        emailArr[0].Substring(emailArr[0].Length - 1),
        emailArr[1][0],
        emailArr[1].Substring(emailArr[1].Length - domainExt.Length - 1, 1),
        domainExt
        );

    return maskedEmail;
}
```

Results

```
info@stakofervlow.com          >>  i****o@s****w.com
me@google.nl                   >>  m****e@g****e.nl
webmaster@stack.over.flow.org  >>  w****r@s****w.org
test@noextension               >>  t****t@n****n
x@y.net                        >>  x****x@y****y.net
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static string EmailStarString(string email)
    {          
        string[] parts = email.Split('@');
        string star = string.Empty;
        string firstCharEmailName = parts[0].First().ToString();
        string lastCharEmailName = parts[0].Last().ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts[0].Length - 2; i++)
        {
            star += "*";
        }
        return firstCharEmailName + star + lastCharEmailName + "@" + parts[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take another approach, one knows that @ is an email address, if there are letters before the @ and letters and a @***.** after the @ sign then take out the section of the text between the spaces that contains a @ and a the dot ".", now we can safely filter those that are to short to be a email

```
var parts = someText.Split(' ').ToArray();                                
for (var i=0;i<parts.Length;i++)
{
    if (parts[i].Length>5 && parts[i].Any(a => a.Equals('@')) && parts[i].Any(a => a.Equals('.')))
    {
        parts[i] = "EMAIL@REMOVED.COM";
    }
}

someText = string.Join(' ', parts);
```

You can replace the whole block in the white-space or go fancy and replace some letters or words. not as fancy as regex voodoo but works for me. by the way, you can also capture things like email(a)mydomain[dot]com by including this in you "any" logic